# Infinite Scrolling - Windows Phone 7/8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7.1, scrollviewer

I'm trying to implement the "infinite scrolling" within a Windows Phone 7.1 project.

Most other posts point to this [MSDN Blog link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx).

I'm struggling to implement this though, because it doesn't really give much away as to how it works or where to put the code.  Also, when I paste the code, it appears to have spaces missing, so I have been through the code and added missing spaces and editing it to the best of my knowledge.

I have added the XAML code to the `<Application.Resources>` of the `App.xaml` is this correct, here is the contents of my `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application 
    x:Class="ScrollWindowBottom.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling">
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VerticalCompression">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoVerticalCompression"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CompressionTop"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CompressionBottom"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HorizontalCompression">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoHorizontalCompression"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CompressionLeft"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CompressionRight"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="Auto" Width="5" 
HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" 
Orientation="Vertical" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" />
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="Auto" Height="5" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" 
Orientation="Horizontal" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Here's my `MainPage.xaml.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace ScrollWindowBottom
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
     { 
         if(!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded) 
         { 
             App.ViewModel.LoadData(); 
         } 

         if(alreadyHookedScrollEvents) 
             return; 

         alreadyHookedScrollEvents = true; 
         MainListBox.AddHandler(ListBox.ManipulationCompletedEvent, (EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>)LB_ManipulationCompleted, true); 
         sb = (ScrollBar)FindElementRecursive(MainListBox, typeof(ScrollBar)); 
         sv = (ScrollViewer)FindElementRecursive(MainListBox, typeof(ScrollViewer)); 

         if(sv != null) 
         { 
             // Visual States are always on the first child of the control template 
            FrameworkElement element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sv, 0) as FrameworkElement; 
             if(element != null) 
             { 
                 VisualStateGroup group = FindVisualState(element, "ScrollStates"); 
                 if(group != null) 
                 { 
                     group.CurrentStateChanging += newEventHandler<VisualStateChangedEventArgs>(group_CurrentStateChanging); 
                 } 
                 VisualStateGroup vgroup = FindVisualState(element, "VerticalCompression"); 
                 VisualStateGroup hgroup = FindVisualState(element, "HorizontalCompression"); 
                 if(vgroup != null) 
                 { 
                     vgroup.CurrentStateChanging += newEventHandler<VisualStateChangedEventArgs>(vgroup_CurrentStateChanging); 
                 } 
                 if(hgroup != null) 
                 { 
                     hgroup.CurrentStateChanging += newEventHandler<VisualStateChangedEventArgs>(hgroup_CurrentStateChanging); 
                 } 
             } 
         }           

     }

  private UIElement FindElementRecursive(FrameworkElement parent, Type targetType) 
       { 
           int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); 
           UIElement returnElement = null; 
           if (childCount > 0) 
           { 
               for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) 
               { 
                   Object element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i); 
                   if (element.GetType() == targetType) 
                   { 
                       return element as UIElement; 
                   } 
                   else 
                   { 
                       returnElement = FindElementRecursive(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as FrameworkElement, targetType); 
                   } 
               } 
           } 
           return returnElement; 
       }


       private VisualStateGroup FindVisualState(FrameworkElement element, string name) 
       { 
           if (element == null) 
               return null; 

           IList groups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(element); 
           foreach (VisualStateGroup group in groups) 
               if (group.Name == name) 
                   return group; 

           return null; 
       }
    }
}
```

With these two pieces of code in place, when I try to run my application to the Emulator I just get a load of errors:

[image]

Comment: We'll need to see your xaml.

Comment: Sorry, it's the XAML from the MSDN blog.  I'll put it in there.

Comment: I have added the full contents of my `App.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml.cs`

Comment: Sorry I mean the XAML from `MainPage.xaml`. It seems like the main issue stems from `MainListBox` not existing.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the full contents of both now.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can't see the XAML from `MainPage.xaml`? I don't mean the C# :D

Comment: BTW, this may be better achieved using `LongListSelector` from the Windows Phone Toolkit (http://phone.codeplex.com/), especially if you're just starting out with your infinite scrolling implementation. See this link for more info: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx

Comment: All I have in my MainPage.xaml is a single `<ScrollViewer>`.  I haven't made use of the additional code yet, because it just comes up with the errors.

Comment: *That's* the reason it comes up with the errors, it's relying on controls being there that you haven't defined. If you really want to use this legacy method, I would suggest downloading the ZIP file in your linked MSDN Blog Article and taking a look at/stealing the source there :)

Comment: Ohh yes! I didn't see that ZIP file!  Thank you for your help.  Feel free to post that as a solution and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're missing the main XAML required, ie. the `MainListBox` element on `MainPage.xaml`. You have added code that references it from the article, but not actually got a `ListBox` on the page you're trying to use it on.

I would recommend downloading the ZIP file from your linked MSDN Blog Article and taking a look at the full example to see what code you'll need from there.

Note also that this solution is the older method of doing it, and a new way using `LongListSelector` is now recommended. For more reference see [this blog post from Microsoft on LongListSelector](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx) and also the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to get hold of `LongListSelector` for your own projects (note that it is included natively in Windows Phone 8).

Comment: Thank you Rudi, I will take a look at the `LongListSelector"!