# Infinite horizontal scrolling / loop items - windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, infinite-scroll

I have a few images in a horizontal scrollable listbox. When the user scrolls to the last image, I want to display the first image after that image, so the user can infinite scroll. I'm using c#.

Thanks

Comment: What might work best is for you to try something and post your code here so that others can help. Just asking for someone to go and write some code for you isn't the way it is supposed to work on SO.

Answer (score 0):

And here as it seems someone answered you'r question: [Infinite Scrolling - Windows Phone 7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234633/infinite-scrolling-windows-phone-7-8)
And MSDN blog on this: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx

But if you still want to create something on you'r own:

I suggest you try to do .RemoveAt(i) and .InsertAt(Listbox.Items.Count-1) that will remove item from first indexes and place them into last, which will create infinite scrolling feel.

But i can't remember/find code snippet for when item comes into view, you must google for it. The idea is, when one of last ListBox items scrolls into view ( user can see it ) you do the .RemoveAt(i) and .InsertAt(Listbox.Items.Count-1).